# Purging a Package Is About to Purge a Lot of Dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, emacs, purge

I was experimenting with having two different versions of Emacs (24 and 25) side-by-side on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. Now I would like to remove Emacs 25 because it errored during the installation (different story).

When I run the command to do so, I see that it wants to remove a lot of dependencies. I do not know much about these packages. How critical are they? Are all of them due to Emacs installation? I do not recall Emacs requiring 500MB of space. Typically it is about 90MB.

```
user@user-desktop:/$ sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove emacs25
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  audacity-data* emacs-snapshot-common* emacs25* gcc-5-base:i386*
  gir1.2-keybinder-3.0* libasound2:i386* libasyncns0:i386* libchromaprint0*
  libcrypto++9v5* libdbus-1-3:i386* libechonest2.3* libfftw3-single3:i386*
  libflac++6v5* libflac8:i386* libftgl2* libgomp1:i386* libice6:i386*
  libid3tag0* libjack-jackd2-0:i386* libjson-c2:i386* libkeybinder-3.0-0*
  liblastfm1* liblilv-0-0* libllvm4.0* libllvm5.0* libltdl7:i386*
  libogg0:i386* liborc-0.4-0:i386* libportsmf0v5* libprojectm2v5* libqjson0*
  libqmi-glib1* libqpdf17* libqxt-core0* libqxt-gui0* libsamplerate0:i386*
  libsbsms10* libserd-0-0* libsm6:i386* libsndfile1:i386* libsodium18*
  libsord-0-0* libsoundtouch1* libspeexdsp1:i386* libsratom-0-0*
  libstdc++6:i386* libsuil-0-0* libsystemd0:i386* libtdb1:i386* libudev1:i386*
  libvamp-hostsdk3v5* libvorbis0a:i386* libvorbisenc2:i386*
  libwebrtc-audio-processing-0:i386* libwrap0:i386* libwxbase3.0-0v5*
  libwxgtk3.0-0v5* libx11-6:i386* libx11-xcb1:i386* libxau6:i386*
  libxcb1:i386* libxdmcp6:i386* libxext6:i386* libxtst6:i386*
  linux-headers-4.4.0-128* linux-headers-4.4.0-128-generic*
  linux-image-4.4.0-128-generic* linux-image-extra-4.4.0-128-generic*
  projectm-data* ttf-dejavu-core*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 70 to remove and 130 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 561 MB disk space will be freed.
```

Comment: If you only installed `emacs25` recently (or semi-recently), why not go & look in your apt/logs to see what was added when you installed it.  That would be the first thing I'd do if I was in your position.

Comment: @guiverc I tried to install it very recently. However, I have had Emacs 24 for a long time and would like to make sure that that is working without hiccups.

Comment: I would still look in your logs, I just looked in my own apt logs and they go back a year on this box.  I did/do see kernel references which I can't imagine being related to `emacs25` so I suspect your system is using the purge to also do a clean-up, but I usually use snaps if I want two+ versions so I avoid the issue you've got.  I would still look for the emacs25 install as whatever was added at the time should be removed (unless it is used by other apps added to your system since then)

Comment: I am not very familiar with this task. Where should I look?

Comment: Your logs are in /var/log/  with apt|dpkg (or packaging task) logs in /var/log/apt/.  The most recent will be history.log, with older files gzip'd (to save space) & also there (`zcat` would be used to view a .gz file instead of usual `cat` etc)

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get autoremove` first to separate out the purge packages from the normal housecleaning.